# Особенности среды разработки Python Django (Windows, Linux, Linux server)

Tags: python, linux, django

Поскольку размещение web-приложения, которое пишется на Python Django,  выгоднее сделать на linux-server'e, то в какой конфигурации среды удобнее заниматься разработкой?
Варианты сред:
1. Windows, Visual Studio, Python Django
2. Linux, PyCharme IDE, Python Django (либо sublime и др.)
3. Linux-Server (один ПК для разработки и на нём же размещение), PyCharme IDE, Python Django (либо sublime и др.)

Какие трудности или дополнительные настройки/особенности web-проекта могут возникнуть в каждом варианте?

Comment: Уточню вопрос. Чем чревата разработка в Django на том же сервере linux, на который и будет установлено web-приложение? Есть ли в данном случае какие-то преимущества или специфические особенности реализации ПО?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нету никакой разницы что вы будете использовать при разработке.
Я сам пользуюсь и рекомендую другим вот такой вариант:
(Windows or Linux) + PyCharm + Anaconda
но это не более чем рекомендация, лично мне наиболее удобна вот такая связка

PyCharm позволяет очень удобно работать с кодом, куча инструментов и т.д., дебаг, отладка.. я уже несколько раз пытался перейти с него на Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, Eclipse, но никогда так и не получалось. Писать на питоне в Sublime Text я бы и врагу не посоветовал.

По поводу Python:
Anaconda имеет довольно широкий набор встроенных питоновских библиотек со старта, кроме этого у неё есть встроенные "окружения" (environments), в которых можно настраивать различные конфигурации (выбор версии питона, установка необходимых модулей и т.д.). Переключение между environment занимает несколько секунд и вы уже можете запустить другой проект с другой конфигурацией питона без каких либо проблем
Также анаконда в связке с pycharm позволяют легко настраивать environments, указывать различные окружения для разных проектов и т.д. - что тоже довольно удобно